# Can you help me with this dropdown menus?

Tags: html, css

I am using this code for dropdown menus, which for some reason does not work.

```css
.tabs__tabs ul {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tabs__tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabs__tabs a {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  color: #8795ae;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #d5dae3;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 55px;
}

.tabs__tabs a.on {
  color: #e84427;
  border-color: #e84427;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabs__content {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabs__content.on {
  display: block;
}

.tabs__content>.pad {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.tabs__content>.block-wrap {
  padding: 10px 30px 30px;
}

.tabs--block .tabs__tabs ul {
  background: #2a4596;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.tabs--block .tabs__tabs a {
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.56);
  border-color: #2a4596;
}

.tabs--block .tabs__tabs a.on {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #e84427;
}

.tabs--block .tabs__content>.pad {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

ul[data-tabs-count="1"] li {
  width: 100%
}

ul[data-tabs-count="2"] li {
  width: 50%
}

ul[data-tabs-count="3"] li {
  width: 33.3333333%
}

ul[data-tabs-count="4"] li {
  width: 25%
}

ul[data-tabs-count="5"] li {
  width: 20%
}

ul[data-tabs-count="6"] li {
  width: 16.666667%
}

ul[data-tabs-count="7"] li {
  width: 14.285714%
}

@media screen and (min-width:450px) {
  .tabs__tabs a {
    min-height: 0;
  }
}

.resp {
  display: none;
}

.resp.open {
  display: block
}

@media screen and (min-width:762px) {
  .resp--med {
    display: block;
  }
  .resp--med-i {
    display: inline;
  }
  .resp-hide--med {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="entry-nav tabs__tabs js-tabs resp resp--med">
  <!-- NOTE: Tabs count added as a data attribute, can be added via js if required and used to size correctly -->
  <ul data-tabs-count="3" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
      <a href="#word" id="aTabEntryword_original" class="on eqh" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" data-target-updtext="#word" style="min-height: 0px; visibility: hidden;">Test1</a><a href="#word" id="aTabEntryword" class="on" data-toggle="tab"
        role="tab" aria-expanded="true" data-target-updtext="#word" style="min-height: 0px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 5px;">Test1</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
      <a href="#trans" id="aTabEntrytrans_original" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" data-target-updtext="#trans" style="min-height: 0px; visibility: hidden;" class="eqh">Test2</a><a href="#trans" id="aTabEntrytrans" class="" data-toggle="tab"
        role="tab" aria-expanded="true" data-target-updtext="#trans" style="min-height: 0px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 5px;">Test2</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown" style="position: relative;">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="aTabEntryeditor_original" data-toggle="dropdown" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" data-target-updtext="javascript:void(0)" style="min-height: 0px; visibility: hidden;" class="eqh">Test3</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="aTabEntryeditor" class="" data-toggle="dropdown" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" data-target-updtext="javascript:void(0)" style="min-height: 0px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 5px;">Test3<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#editor">SubTest1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#editor2">SubTest1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The drop down menu on tab Test3 does not show up. There is also underline if you go with cursor to test2 and test3. Can someone look into my CSS code and give me some useful advice, please?

Comment: can you add a code snippet with your whole code that would be easy to edit

Comment: Hereby the [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/j04auumg/). Thank you!

Comment: <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
you need to add the js  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: this better? https://jsfiddle.net/j04auumg/2/

Comment: @MichaelCoker, thank you for helping me out. It works. I'll see if the border beneath the subname can be undone. Greetings!

Comment: You can use `.tabs__tabs > ul > li > a` to target just the top level links for the border. https://jsfiddle.net/j04auumg/3/

Comment: @MichaelCoker, for some reason it does not work when I put it in my css file. Maybe something inside the whole css is blocking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use bootstrap you have not need to use javascript for dropdown menus.

Follow this link to know more information about bootstrap dropdown menu.
https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar